# SPSS: Zero df and no value in F and Sig

Tags: anova, spss

When I tried SPSS two-way ANOVA analysis, the result shows df is zero,and no value in F, Sig, and Mean square.

Does anyone know why this happened? Does it mean I need to input more data to analysis?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yep. You can't say anything about the interaction between Gender and Education because all the Female subjects have UG Education.

Comment: @DoctorMilt Ok I got it. Thank you so much.